# Custom hair particle system - wrong directions

Tags: modeling, particles

I'm trying to create a hair particle system on a sphere. Standard hair particles works exactly like I need, pointing at different directions opposite to the sphere center:

[image]

But when I replace them with custom particles, the directions are wrong.

[image]

How can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a few issues:

1. Make sure the origin is at the bottom of your particle object. <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> on the bottom of the object, then press <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>, then press *origin to 3D cursor*:

[image]

2. The rotation of your objects looks off. In the hair emitter's particle settings under *Render*, check *Rotation*:

[image]

Then, in the settings of the object being duplicated as hair, rotate the object until it looks correct. For me, it was `XYZ 45/90/45`, but it may be different for you:

[image]
[image]